# why does pushing an item into a data array not update the view/vuejs dev tools with the new data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

For some reason, pushing data into an array doesnt update the view/vue dev tools data. Why?

I have cleaned the browser cache without any luck.

```
theArray = [
   [
      {
         test: true
      }
   ]
]

methods: {
   addNewItem() {
     console.log(this.theArray[0].length); // = 1

     this.theArray[0].push({}); 

     console.log(this.theArray[0].length); // = 2. This does however show that the data was pushed but why do the view and vuejs tools not update/show the pushed data?
   }
}
```

However, doing this works for some reason?

```
this.theArray.push({});
```

Comment: Can you please share a minimum example of the working code?

Comment: Where is your theArray defined in data section?

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

That's due to Vue's reactivity. You can use `Vue.set()`/`this.$set()`.

```js
this.$set(theArray, 0, [ ...theArray[0], {} ]);
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Comment: That doesnt work either. Gives same problem

Comment: Maybe `theArray[0]` isn't reactive either … 